# Alternatives for Gaussian elimination transform and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, math

Gaussian elimination algorithm in transform and conquer has O(n<sup>3</sup>) complexity. Is there any technique that give more efficient complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Do you want to invert a matrix or to solve a system ? For solving systems don't use GE. For inverting matrices, there are algorithms which pay off when n is large. See @Roland's answer. Usually you use GE, and you **never write it yourself**.

Comment: @AlexandreC. For solving system, what other algorithms can be used

Answer (score 3):

There are algorithms for matrix inversion with better asymptotic complexity, e.g., the Strassen algorithm with complexity O(n<sup>2.807</sup>) and the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) with complexity O(n<sup>2.376</sup>).

(Note that the complexity of matrix multiplication and matrix inversion are [the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra))

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which complexity you measure:

Number of multiplications: No, by changing the technique you can only worsen the complexity of Gaussian elimination.

Number of time steps: Yes, parallel implementation of the row operations reduces time complexity to O(n).